# jquery mobile select box content is in middle of select box

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

ive been looking through the documentation for jquery mobile trying to work out how to left align all text within the select boxes..

Ive tried various things like

```
$("select").addClass('ui-btn-left');
```

and making sure that the rules for the class align the text to the left but no luck, ive also tried

```
#('select').parent().addClass('ui-btn-left');
```

but this also doesnt appear to work.

Ive also tried to create a css rule to make it global so that all select boxes have their text aligned to the left.. but no luck here either.

Any suggestions as im strugling to understand how this works..

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in your CSS file you have maintained text align = center or something like that.
Put text-align ; left in body.